# Distinguo is a fun word

Tags: discussion, comments

This is just a suggestion, but I heard it a few times in a homily that my Parish's priest likes to tell year after year and I thought I should bring it up here for the betterment and personal improvement of all involved.  If you're trying to separate a theological point from the assumption that someone made about what they thought you were talking about say:

> [*distinguo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinguo)

Before telling them why they're wrong.

for example:

> @rubarb_head *Distinguo*, you are gravely mistaken, soon I'll be dead and you with me. Surrender or die.

or

> @pet *Distinguo* you have grossly conflated two alike things in a confusing manner

Again, this is just a suggestion, but I think if we could get more *distinguo*'s out there we could probably understand each other a little better.

Comment: I agree, and expect to see this turn up occasionally in my comments!

Comment: Why not use an English word instead? What would be a good translation?

Comment: "I separate/distinguish [your argument from my original point]"